# Learning OpenGL ES 2.0, Coming From 2D

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, 3d, shader

My new job has me moving from a 2D graphics environment (old job) to a 3D environment using OpenGL ES 2.0. I'm looking for hints, book suggestions, awesome tutorials, and possible test environments or OpenGL ES 2.0 emulators to help me make the jump.

I have basic familiarity with OpenGL ES 1.X's fixed function pipeline, but I'm completely new to shaders and programmable pipelines.

Specifically, anything that discusses basic 2D concepts (rects, lines, blits, blending, etc) in terms of 3D geometry and shaders would be particularly helpful.

Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't got a direct example of what you're looking for. Though you don't really have to get into shaders at first.

It's not OpenGL-ES, but I've been in a slightly dissimilar situation and found http://nehe.gamedev.net/ an interesting starting point. The caveat obviously being that the tutorials are full OpenGL, then again it is useful to discover what is different in OpenGL-ES as there's lots of code in the web.

Also, OpenGLES on the iPhone is not a bad place to look around as the iPhone has a capable GPU and many people are interested in writing GL apps for it.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the NeHe tutorials covered (some) GLSL as well. Neat.

Comment: Unfortunately though, as you mention, they don't cover OpenGL ES's limitations.